# Find highest MACD over specific period

Tags: pine-script

I am currently building my first pine scripts and want to have the following check

`check5 = (macd(close,12,26,9) > highest (macd(close,12,26,9), 40))` --> i.e. I want to check if the macd of today is larger than the highest macd over the last 40 days ...

Unfortunately I get this error: Cannot call 'highest' with arguments ([series[float], series[float], series[float]], literal integer); available overloads: highest(series[float], integer) => series[float]; highest(series[float], series[integer]) => series[float]; highest(integer) => series[float]; highest(series[integer]) => series[float];

I have googled for a couple of hours but cannot find a solution to my problem... would strongly appreciate if someone could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built-in `macd` function return [3 variables](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_macd) as a result, you have to chose which one of them you wish to evaluate with `>` operator, in the example below the script check the macdLine values:

```
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
check5 = macdLine > highest(macdLine, 40)
```

Comment: thanks - very helpful. How can I adjust the check in a way that I check the past 40 days, i.e. not including today's macdLine? 

i.e. if today is the highest value then the check as it is written now would always include today in the 40 days and thus, turn out false. however, I want to exclude today from "highest(macdLine, 40)"

Comment: found it myself - with [1] it should work, i.e. 
check5 = macdLine > highest(macdLine, 40)[1]